# How to increase HTTP header size in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, http-headers, jupyter, tornado

When working with matplotlib widgets and k3d to visualize 3D data, the requests are constructed such, that the graphical data is being packed into the HTTP header. This header size is limited in the underlying webserver used by jupyter server (tornado). If it is exceeded by the client request (e.g. visualizing a large plot), the following exception pops up in the log file of Jupyter:

```
[I 2021-11-30 15:42:35.323 ServerApp] Unsatisfiable read, closing connection: delimiter re.compile(b'\r?\n\r?\n') not found within 65536 bytes
```

So the buffer size of 64 KiB has been exceeded by the plot.

My question is how to permanently set a larger header size within Jupyter? I already tried something like this:

jupyter_server_config.py:

```py
c.ServerApp.tornado_settings = {
    "max_header_size": 500*1024**2,
    "max_buffer_size": 1024**3,
}
```

WITHOUT any success.

Here is a related bug report with this error message:
https://github.com/codota/TabNine/issues/255 suggesting that

> "...changed the Tornado package's code because there does not seem to
> be a directive to pass options to the HTTPServer object in Jupyter's
> configuration."

I hope this does not hold true, but can be manipulated sanely somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope this does not hold true, but can be manipulated sanely somehow.

Well, monkey patching is always an option in dynamic languages such as Python.

We're going to patch Tornado's [http connection parameters](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/http1connection.py#L71-L101) and override the `max_header_size`.

Put this code in your `jupyter_server_config.py` file:

```py
from tornado import http1connection

def init_patch(
    self,
    no_keep_alive=False,
    chunk_size=None,
    max_header_size=None,
    header_timeout=None,
    max_body_size=None,
    body_timeout=None,
    decompress=False,
):
    self.no_keep_alive = no_keep_alive
    self.chunk_size = chunk_size or 65536
    self.max_header_size = 500*1024**2 # <- custom value
    self.header_timeout = header_timeout
    self.max_body_size = max_body_size
    self.body_timeout = body_timeout
    self.decompress = decompress

http1connection.HTTP1ConnectionParameters.__init__ = init_patch
```

Comment: Thanks! This would assume, that init will be called after reading the config. I think that, the Configurable interface the http server class implements, allows for later changing its values.

Comment: Now I see, that you're patching the connection object, that's very clever!

Answer (score 0):

If the signature of this class would change, we got a problem, so this solution based on @xyres monkey patching avoids running into future changes. It also wraps everything in a function to keep the namespace clean.

```py
def patch_tornado_header_size():
    from tornado import http1connection

    init_orginal = http1connection.HTTP1ConnectionParameters.__init__

    def init_patch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        init_orginal(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.max_header_size = 500 * 1024 ** 2

    http1connection.HTTP1ConnectionParameters.__init__ = init_patch


patch_tornado_header_size()
```

Comment: this does assume, that the constructor does simply store the header size, and does NOT compute anything based on it in this call.